# Reconnect RMI client after server restart

Tags: java, connection, rmi, restart

I have an RMI server and a desktop RMI client. When I restart the server, I get errors in the client. Is it possible to restart the RMI connection without restarting the client?

[EDIT] Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at ...user code...
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:574)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:185)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:171)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:94)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:179)
    at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
    at $Proxy0.search(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:592)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptorUtils.invokeRemoteMethod(RmiClientInterceptorUtils.java:108)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.doInvoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:362)
    at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.invoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:258)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at $Proxy1.search(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:367)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:524)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:474)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:371)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:184)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:22)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:128)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:569)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: what sort of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the server is terminated, you will receive a ConnectException. After that you can just use [Naming.lookup](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/rmi/Naming.html#lookup%28java.lang.String%29) to get a new server object.

Comment: If the server has restarted you may get a `NoSuchObjectException` instead.

Answer (score 23):

If you're using Spring (namely [`RmiProxyFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/remoting.html#remoting-rmi)), you can simply set the property `refreshStubOnConnectFailure` to `true` and the bean will survive a restart of the server.

```
<property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true" />
```

Comment: I was using spring. this helped me.

Comment: brilliant, a big thanks to both spring and yourself for the answer :)

Comment: But How do I make the client start with out the server Up? Because the bean cannot connect...

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez Try to use a lazy bean or a factory.

Comment: @FelipeGutierrez, there is [`lookupStubOnStartup`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/remoting/rmi/RmiClientInterceptor.html#setLookupStubOnStartup-boolean-) property for this. Setting it to `false` should allow your client to startup when RMI server is still not started.

Comment: for java config: rmiProxyFactory.setRefreshStubOnConnectFailure(true)