# Spring RMI refreshStubOnConnectFailure not working

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I read the following blog entry here,
[Reconnect RMI client after server restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477121/reconnect-rmi-client-after-server-restart/1485920#1485920)

It states that when the property refreshStubOnConnectFailure is set to true that my client RMI will try to reconnect to the server. So I wrote the following code to test it out before I put changes into my system. I started my server and then this test program. After a few messages that the server and client were talking I stopped the server. I got an exception trace but none of my catch blocks was entered. As usual I am confused because I thought at least one of my catch blocks would be executed. My program output follows.

```
Main starting
Hi There Received
Hi There Received
Hi There Received
Jan 05, 2016 9:32:06 PM org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean handleRemoteConnectFailure
WARNING: Could not connect to RMI service [rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/Ping] - retrying
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Lookup of RMI stub failed; nested exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:215)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.refreshAndRetry(RmiClientInterceptor.java:326)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.handleRemoteConnectFailure(RmiClientInterceptor.java:307)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.invoke(RmiClientInterceptor.java:267)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1.sayHello(Unknown Source)
at com.edvs.main.TestIt.main(TestIt.java:34)
Caused by: java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:101)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:200)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
... 13 more
```

My code follows:

```
package com.edvs.main;
import java.rmi.ConnectException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import com.edvs.service.PingService;

public class TestIt {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String file = "bean.xml";
    ApplicationContext context = null;
    try {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception:" + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(99);
    }

    System.out.println("Main starting");
    PingService ps = (PingService) context.getBean("pingBean");
    boolean done = false;
    int count = 30;

    if (ps != null) {
        while (!done && count > 0) {
            try {
                if (ps.sayHello("Annapolis").equals("hi there")) {
                    System.out.println("Hi There Received");
                }
            } catch (ConnectException ce) {
                System.out.println("ConnectionException");
                /*
                 * Something happened with the server so see if it is
                 * something we should retry the connection.
                 */

                if (ce.getMessage().contains("Connection refused")) {
                    System.out.println("Connection Refused");
                }

            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                System.out.println("RemoteException:" + e.getMessage());
            }
            count--;

            try {
                Thread.yield();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }

    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();

    System.out.println("Test has ended.");
  }
}
```

bean.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">


<bean id="pingBean" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/Ping" />
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="com.edvs.service.PingService" />
    <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true" />
    <property name="lookupStubOnStartup" value="false" />
</bean>
```

None of the exceptions are caught. The application just terminates. If I comment out refreshStubOnConnectFailure then the ConnectionException exception is thrown, but I don't know how to restart the connection once the server is restarted.

For completeness and for others to gaze at, I am adding my final test code. It tests for the server initially and then continues to converse with the server.

```
package com.edvs.main;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.rmi.ConnectException;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean;

import com.edvs.service.PingService;

public class TestIt {
static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(TestIt.class.getName());

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String file = "bean.xml";

    ApplicationContext context = null;
    try {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(file);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception:" + e.getMessage());
        System.exit(99);
    }

    System.out.println("Main starting");
    log.info("foo");

    boolean done = false;
    int count = 30;

    RmiProxyFactoryBean rpfb = (RmiProxyFactoryBean) context.getBean("&pingBean");
    String serviceUrl = rpfb.getServiceUrl();

    /*
     * See if the server is there as we startup.
     */
    while (true) {
        if (null != isServerThere(serviceUrl)) {
            /*
             * The server is there so continue with our processing.
             */
            break;
        } else {
            /*
             * The server is not there so sleep and then try again.
             */
            try {
                Thread.yield();
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.exit(33);
            }
        }
    }

    PingService ps = (PingService) context.getBean("pingBean");

    try {
        log.info("Service Name:" + ps.getServiceName());
        log.info("all:" + ps.toString());
        log.info("serviceUrl:" + rpfb.getServiceUrl());

    } catch (RemoteException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (!done && count > 0) {

        try {
            if (ps.sayHello("Annapolis").equals("hi there")) {
                log.info("Hi There Received");
            }
        } catch (ConnectException ce) {
            log.info("ConnectionException");
            /*
             * Something happened with the server so see if it is something we
             * should retry the connection.
             */

            if (ce.getMessage().contains("Connection refused")) {
                log.info("Connection Refused");
                ps = (PingService) isServerThere(serviceUrl);
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            System.out.println("RemoteException:" + e.getMessage());
        }
        count--;

        try {
            Thread.yield();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            done = true;
        }
    }

    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();

    System.out.println("Test has ended.");
}

static private Remote isServerThere(String serviceUrl) {
    Remote remote = null;

    try {
        remote = Naming.lookup(serviceUrl);

    } catch (MalformedURLException | RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
        log.error("Exception:" + e.getMessage());
    }

    return remote;
}
}
```

Comment: Have you actually looked at the stack trace? You are getting one of the specialized exceptions from the spring exception hierarchy NOT the plain RMI exceptions. So basically your catch block isn't doing anything. Spring converts those into `RuntimeException`s. If you look even closer you see that a reconnection attempt is actually being done (`refreshAndRetry` which in turn leads to an unrecoverable exception). So basically it is working but as there still is no server. This exception bubbles up and basically blows up your application. (as that is how you designed it).

Comment: This is true. How would I allow the client to continually retry until the server comes back up. Like put in a delay of 30 seconds and retry. This is a problem because I could have 100 clients talking to the server when it crashes. I would not want all of them to crash too. I would be on the phone from now to the end of time telling people to restart their clients.

Comment: Just catch `RemoteAccessException` and your loop will continue. Maybe put a `Thread.sleep` in there.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `connection refused` *to the Registry*. No amount of re-looking up is going to fix that, because the Regsitry isn't running. So that's what you need to fix.

The property you're setting takes effect when you get a connection refusal *to your remote object*.

Comment: I guess I was not clear. The client and server are running just fine. The Ping transaction is just running along. I terminate the server and the client fails with connection refused. I did a debug trace and found that RMI is retrying the connection after the failure one time and then quits. There must be a way to allow the client to continually retry until the server comes back up.

Comment: Maybe there is, I am no Spring expert, but there isn't in RMI, and the Spring property you're setting doesn't do it either.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an answer in this forum that mentions Naming.lookup(). I changed the code in the catch block for ConnectionException. That code now looks like the following.

```
if (ce.getMessage().contains("Connection refused")) {
  log.info("Connection Refused");
  try {
    ps = (PingService)Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1:1099/Ping");
  } catch (MalformedURLException | RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
    log.info("Naming Exception:" + e.getMessage());
  }
}
```

The Naming.lookup() will continue to fail until the server comes backup. Once the server is restarted then a new PingService object is retrieved and then can be used. I think this is correct and would appreciate the forums comments.

Comment: That will retry once. Is that all you need? without a sleep?

Comment: The whole catch block is useless as there is no `ConnectException` or `RemoteException` thrown. How much you modify the content of those catch blocks it will not help because it will never be reached. Not to mention that it completely beats the purpose of having Spring Remoting in the first place as you are now bypassing that.

Comment: Thank you for that comment. I removed the <property name="refreshStubOnConnectFailure" value="true" />. Now the catch block works and I am able to retry by continuously using Naming.lookup() until the server comes back up. Once up the Naming.lookup() is successful and I am running again.