# Spring RMI server and pure java RMI client

Tags: java, spring, rmi

I have two peers to connect though RMI. At the RMI server side I am using Spring inerfaces (http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-remoting-rmi.jsp). At the RMI client side I need to start it with out know if the server is UP. So if I use spring my client does not start and I have connection refused exception.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
        <property name="serviceName" value="RestoreRMIService" />
        <property name="serviceInterface" value="br.com.eb.service.iscsi.RestoreService" />
        <property name="service" ref="restoreService" />
    </bean>
```

So I tried to use pure java RMI on the client side (http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/articles/javarmi/javarmi.html). But I am getting ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy73 cannot be cast to br.com.eb.service.iscsi.RestoreService. I beliave because I don't have stubs from my RMI server.

I wnat pure java RMI on the client side because I need to be able to restart the server side.

```
protected void connectRMI() {
        if (!rmiConected) {
            try {
                Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
                serviceRestore = (RestoreService) registry.lookup("RestoreRMIService");
                // serviceRestore = (RestoreService) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/RestoreRMIService");
                rmiConected = true;
            } catch (ConnectException ce) {
                System.err.println("Error: server not started");
                rmiConected = false;
            } catch (ConnectIOException cioe) {
                System.err.println("Error: Cannot connect to server at 127.0.0.1");
                rmiConected = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You don't need to switch RMI implementations just to solve a 'connection refused' exception.
- Java RMI gets 'connection refused' exceptions too.
- Java RMI and Spring RMI do not interoperate.

  Your question doesnt make sense.

Comment: I see, thanks!. I found this > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477121/reconnect-rmi-client-after-server-restart

Comment: But How do I make the client start with out the server Up? Because the bean cannot connect...